# How to reload any slickgrid dataview dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slickgrid, dataview

How to reload any slickgrid dataview?

Is there any methods in slickgrid API to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dataView.setItems([new_data])`.  You shouldn't need anything else.

Comment: How to reload grid where I just changed preferences(width, height,columns order) only(no data is added)  to get that grid with old preferences?

Comment: For columns, just change them via `grid.setColumns()`.  If the container is resized, call `grid.resizeCanvas()`.

Answer (score 0):

Also take a look at [DataView](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/DataView), a custom data provider Leibman created. Looks like anything that implements `getLength()`, `getItem(idx)`, and `getItemMetadata(idx)` can provide data.

Looks like the way to go if you have a large data set and want awesome performance.